# MapView doesn't load if network is off and the output console return errors

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, mkmapview, runtime-error

I need to your support.
My app uses a MKMapView to show a map. I tested it on emulator and on my iPhone, but when network is ON it works perfectly, when network is OFF it doesn't load and the output console return these errors:

```
 Could not determine current country code: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x7f800e0e7520 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f800e0207c0 "The Internet connection appears to be offline.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://gsp1.apple.com/pep/gcc, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://gsp1.apple.com/pep/gcc, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}
```

Are these errors normal? Or the must be handled? I don't know how can I fix these errors, and in which map view's func do I check the network connection.

Thanks and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

You should check first if you are connected to the network - if not, you could not use a map).

Try something like this:

```
func hasConnection() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
}
```

And if its false, you should disable the map.

Comment: And where should I check my connection network? My app starts and after launchImage show the map

Comment: Then in "ViewWillLoad" in your mainViewController.

Comment: I have one dupt: can I do like Maps app of Apple that stars map even when network is off?

Comment: There is an offline cache. But you can also check something like that: https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit

Comment: A question: if I leave everything so (with errors in console), sul Apple refuse my App? Or they are a simples warning errors?

Comment: It depends what your app does. if its a App, which requires a internet connection, just write an error message, that you need to connect to WLAN or 3G first to use the app. Then it should not be a problem. There are lots of apps which are useless without having a internet connection. i would create a custom login/welcome screen, and then proof the connection.

Comment: Is there a func to redirect to iPhone settings? maybe directly in wifi or cellular data section?